# iframe and background images with IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, iframe

I am trying to insert a background image into an `iframe` and while it works exactly as expected in Firefox, IE is completely ignoring it:

```
<iframe style="background: #ffffff url('/images/load.gif') no-repeat fixed center; width:100%; height:100%;" id="frm" align="middle" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

In case it matters, the background image is an animated "loading" GIF and the `src` property of the `iframe` gets set dynamically by JS. The idea is that when the source document loads, it overlays the background, prior to that it's just an activity indicator.

I found somewhere that this may be caused by missing or wrong doctype, mine says:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

How can I make IE play nice and display the background for the few seconds the iframe source takes to load.

Comment: first, if src  property of the iframe gets set dynamically by js, why is there url('/images/load.gif') inside your iframe?

Comment: The idea is that the background image shows up right away, and then when the `src` is set (a user clicks a button for that to happen) the requested page loads in the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set the `allowtransparency=true` attribute on the iframe element.
2. Make the iframe's original document's background transparent, perhaps by using `<iframe src="javascript:'<body bgcolor=transparent>';">`